# Insert Geometry and update attribute using arcpy.da.InsertCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to insert geometries from one feature class into another and then update an attribute associated with the geometry. Only inserting the geometry works fine, but I can't work out how to insert the new value associated with the geometry. Below insertRow() gives 'TypeError: cannot read geometry sequence'.

```
import arcpy

aLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
aValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
target = "C:\\local.gdb\\target"
desc = arcpy.Describe(aLayer)
type = desc.shapeType

if type == "Polygon":   
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(target, ["SHAPE@","aField"]) as iCursor:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(aLayer, ["SHAPE@"]) as sCursor:
            for row in sCursor:             
                iCursor.insertRow([row,aValue])
```

Comment: Change `iCursor.insertRow([row,aValue])` to `iCursor.insertRow([row[0],aValue])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to insert a row object within a row object in place of the `SHAPE@` field/attribute. From your search cursor, you need to specify the index of your to-be-copied attribute value, which takes place at row[0].

Therefore, changing `iCursor.insertRow([row,aValue])` to `iCursor.insertRow([row[0],aValue])` will resolve your problem.