# Copy geometry only from one feature class to another based on condition

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, insert

I'm trying to use ArcPy to copy only the geometry from one feature class to another based on a certain condition. Here is my code so far:

```
source_fields = ['contition_field', 'SHAPE@']

icursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(target_fc, 'SHAPE@')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source_fc, source_fields) as scursor:

    for row in scursor:
        if row[0] == 'condition1':
            icursor.insertRow(row[1])
```

When I try to run it, I get this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-bc6790d82eb2> in <module>
      6     for row in scursor:
      7         if row[0] == 'condition1':
----> 8             icursor.insertRow(row[1])
      9 
     10 

TypeError: cannot read geometry sequence. expected list of floats
```

I tried doing a few searches on this error, but it seems like most people don't have a problem with copying geometry, they have problem with copying other fields. However nothing seems to allow me to copy the feature geometry (like in this thread):

[Insert Geometry and update attribute using arcpy.da.InsertCursor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220513/insert-geometry-and-update-attribute-using-arcpy-da-insertcursor)

What is wrong?

Comment: Are the input and output layers the same geometry type and coordinate system?

Comment: `insertRow()` expects a sequence of values but you're passing in a single geometry object, try passing in a single-item list: `icursor.insertRow([row[1]])`

Comment: Thank you very much @mikewatt, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Change `icursor.insertRow(row[1])` to `icursor.insertRow([row[1]])`

Comment: This could be improved by explaining *why* it's the correct answer, and why the former value failed the way it did (Hint: a `Geometry` has an iterator that generates `Point` objects)